# Automate exporting of Excel worksheets to PDF

Tags: excel, powershell

<sup>**Editor's note**: The OP has abandoned this question and asked a variation at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766898/saving-excel-worksheets-to-pdf-using-powershell.</sup>

I have been trying to implement the following PowerShell script but without any luck. Can someone please help?

I know this script will save 1 PDF file per Excel workbook, however once I get this working I will look at exporting each Excel worksheet to separate PDF files.

ExportTo-ExcelPDF.ps1 from http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/06/save-a-microsoft-excel-workbook-as-a-pdf-file-by-using-powershell.aspx

```
$path = "c:\fso" 
$xlFixedFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type] 
$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -include *.xls, *.xlsx -recurse 
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application 
$objExcel.visible = $false 
foreach($wb in $excelFiles) 
{ 
  $filepath = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ($wb.BaseName + ".pdf") 
  $workbook = $objExcel.workbooks.open($wb.fullname, 3) 
  $workbook.Saved = $true 
  "saving $filepath" 
  $workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath) 
  $objExcel.Workbooks.close() 
} 
$objExcel.Quit()
```

Error messages:

```
The property 'Saved' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
property exists and can be set.
At C:\ExportExcel.ps1:23 char:2
+  $workbook.Saved = $true
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException

saving C:\ExportExcel.pdf
Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a
method named 'ExportAsFixedFormat'.
At C:\ExportExcel.ps1:25 char:2
+  $workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat($xlFixedFormat::xlTypePDF, $filepath)
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\ExportExcel.ps1:26 char:2
+  $objExcel.Workbooks.close()
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Exception calling "Quit" with "0" argument(s): "Call was rejected by callee.    
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010001 (RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED))"
At C:\ExportExcel.ps1:28 char:1
+ $objExcel.Quit()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMException
```

Comment: The first error looks like `$workbook` is null, and opening the file failed. The second error looks like `$workbook` is not a workbook object, or maybe the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198122(v=office.14).aspx) saying "*An error will occur if the PDF add-in is not currently installed.*" mean that will happen? The third error is `$objExcel` apparently being `$null`. The combination of errors looks very strange - does it write any PDF files at all? What kind of environment are you running it in? (software versions, how are you running it)?

Comment: No PDF files are created at all. Running on a Server 2012 R2 host / Powershell 4.0 / Office 2016 Pro Plus.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The 1st error doesn't necessarily imply that `$workbook` is `$null` - only that whatever object `$workbook` represents doesn't have a `Saved` property (assuming `Set-StrictMode -Version 2` or higher). Similarly, the 2nd error simply indicates that the object doesn't have method `ExportAsFixedFormat` - the specific parameters don't come into play, so whether the PDF plug-in is installed doesn't matter (yet). The 3rd error most definitely does _not_ imply that `$objExcel` is `$null`. The objects exist, but (some) don't have the expected members, among other issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I went back to the drawing board and got a bit closer to the required result. New post for new issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38766898/saving-excel-worksheets-to-pdf-using-powershell

Comment: @mklement0 "*The 3rd error most definitely does not imply that $objExcel is $null.*" - it does too. Maybe wrongly, with your deeper knowledge, but earlier we see: `$excel.workbooks.open()` is valid, therefore `.workbooks` is a valid property on a good `$objExcel` object. The error says `$excel.workbooks` is `a null valued expression`, it doesn't say `__ does not contain a
property named 'workbooks'`. `$objExcel.x.y()` behaving the same as  `$null.x.y()` implies $objExcel is null. At least a little bit.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: My bad: I meant the _4th_ error (`RPC_E_CALL_REJECTED`); you're right about the 3rd. As you stated: the combination of errors is strange.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

The most likely cause is that Excel's primary interop assembly isn't installed.

---

The error messages suggest that even though you managed the create the Excel-related objects per se, accessing their members (properties and methods) failed.

Sometimes, setting `$VerbosePreference='Continue'` helps; for instance, on my machine I see the following when I instantiate the Excel application object (`New-Object -ComObject excel.application`):

> VERBOSE: The object written to the pipeline is an instance of the type "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass" from the component's primary interoperability assembly. If
>    this type exposes different members than the IDispatch members, scripts that are written to work with this object might not work if the primary interoperability assembly is not
>   installed.

*Perhaps* a missing interoperability assembly is your problem.

On my machine (PSv5, Excel 2010), this interoperability assembly is (a) *not* loaded *by default*, (b) is only loaded *when you instantiate the Excel application object*.

Thus, your code wouldn't work on my machine, because it references type `[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType]` - which is part of that interop assembly - *before* the Excel application object is created, which fails - silently, because the *indirect* type reference `"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type]` simply returns `$null` - without complaining - if the type doesn't exist (yet).

If you instead use `[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType]` directly, you'll instantly get an error if the type doesn't exist / its assembly has not been loaded (yet).

In short:

- Remove line `$xlFixedFormat = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType" -as [type]`.
- In its stead, place `$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType]` *after* the `objExcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application` line.
- Debug your script and run `$objExcel | Get-Member` and `$wb | Get-Member` right after the first `$objExcel.workbooks.open($wb.fullname, 3)` call to see what members PowerShell can see.

  - If the `$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.xlFixedFormatType]` line produces an error right away, or you don't see the members of interest (`Saved`, `ExportAsFixedFormat`, ...), the most likely cause is that the interop assembly isn't installed.
  - Another way to see if the interop assembly is loaded is to execute `[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass]` and see if type information is returned (as opposed to an error message).